# Перемещение графического элемента при нажатии клавиш

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, paintevent, keypressevent

Как разместить в данном коде виджет, чтобы на нем передвигать графические элементы при нажатии на клавишу (например стрелок)?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QMainWindow, QApplication


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

StyleSheet = """
QMainWindow{
    border-image: url(11.png) 0 0 0 0 stretch stretch;
}
"""

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(StyleSheet)                                  
    w = MainWindow()
    w.setWindowTitle("Title MainWindow")
    w.resize(702, 343)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То, что вы задумали, может выглядеть примерно так. Нажимайте на стрелочки.

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Example(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setFixedSize(700, 400)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.x = 300
        self.y = 200


    def up(self):
        self.update()

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_Left:   
            self.x -= 5
        elif event.key() == Qt.Key_Right: 
            self.x += 5
        elif event.key() == Qt.Key_Up: 
            self.y -= 5
        elif event.key() == Qt.Key_Down:
            self.y += 5
        QTimer.singleShot(100, self.up)        

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        if self.x <= -45:
            self.x = 725
        elif self.x >= 725:
            self.x = -45
        if self.y <= -25:
            self.y = 415
        elif self.y >= 415:
            self.y = -25
        self.qp = QPainter()
        self.qp.begin(self)
        self.drawFlag()
        self.qp.end()

    def drawFlag(self):
        self.qp.setBrush(QColor(150, 75, 0))
        self.qp.drawEllipse(self.x, self.y, 50, 20)
        self.qp.setBrush(QColor(0, 255, 255))
        self.qp.drawEllipse(self.x + 10, self.y - 10, 30, 20)


StyleSheet = """
QMainWindow{
    border-image: url(i-700x400.jpg) 0 0 0 0 stretch stretch;
}
"""

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(StyleSheet)
    w = Example()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А можно ли создать для этого отдельный виджет определенных размеров, в пределах которых будет передвигаться данный объект? (то есть он не должен будет выходить за пределы виджета)

Comment: @ZheD1s я же вам уже писал, что все можно. Сделайте попытку реализации вашей идеи самостоятельно, если что-то не будет получатся - предоставите вашу попытку с пояснениями, что вы хотели сделать и что у вас не получилось, но это уже другой вопрос.

Comment: извините,если чем-то озадачил вас, я просто в ступоре, именно этот момент не могу реализовать. Неделю сижу за этой дипломной работой. Я не знаю просто в каком виджете это всё реализовать.

Comment: @ZheD1s вы меня ничем не озадачиваете. Я все делаю в свое удовольствие. нравится мне это. Но мне хочется увидеть какие-то ваши попытки решения, вы же не просто неделю сидите. Покажите что вы пробовали сделать, но это уже другой вопрос.